# Find indices of numpy array based on values in another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to find the indices in a larger array if they match the values of a different, smaller array. Something like `new_array` below:

```
import numpy as np
summed_rows = np.random.randint(low=1, high=14, size=9999)
common_sums = np.array([7,10,13])
new_array = np.where(summed_rows == common_sums)
```

However, this returns:

```
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future. 
>>>new_array 
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

The closest I've gotten is:

```
new_array = [np.array(np.where(summed_rows==important_sum)) for important_sum in common_sums[0]]
```

This gives me a list with three numpy arrays (one for each 'important sum'), but each is a different length which produces further downstream problems with concatenation and vstacking. To be clear, I do *not* want to use the line above. I want to use numpy to index into `summed_rows`. I've looked at various answers using `numpy.where`, `numpy.argwhere`, and `numpy.intersect1d`, but am having trouble putting the ideas together. I figured I'm missing something simple and it would be faster to ask.

Thanks in advance for your recommendations!

Comment: You can do that in one line if I understood properly: `(summed_rows==common_sums[:,None]).any(0).nonzero()[0]`

Comment: np.where(summed_rows == common_sums[:, None])[1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking into account the proposed options on the comments, and adding an extra option with numpy's in1d option:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> summed_rows = np.random.randint(low=1, high=14, size=9999)
>>> common_sums = np.array([7,10,13])
>>> ind_1 = (summed_rows==common_sums[:,None]).any(0).nonzero()[0]   # Option of @Brenlla
>>> ind_2 = np.where(summed_rows == common_sums[:, None])[1]   # Option of @Ravi Sharma
>>> ind_3 = np.arange(summed_rows.shape[0])[np.in1d(summed_rows, common_sums)]
>>> ind_4 = np.where(np.in1d(summed_rows, common_sums))[0]
>>> ind_5 = np.where(np.isin(summed_rows, common_sums))[0]   # Option of @jdehesa

>>> np.array_equal(np.sort(ind_1), np.sort(ind_2))
True
>>> np.array_equal(np.sort(ind_1), np.sort(ind_3))
True
>>> np.array_equal(np.sort(ind_1), np.sort(ind_4))
True
>>> np.array_equal(np.sort(ind_1), np.sort(ind_5))
True
```

If you time it, you can see that all of them are quite similar, but @Brenlla's option is the fastest one

```
python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0); a = np.random.randint(low=1, high=14, size=9999); b = np.array([7,10,13])' 'ind_1 = (a==b[:,None]).any(0).nonzero()[0]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.7 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0); a = np.random.randint(low=1, high=14, size=9999); b = np.array([7,10,13])' 'ind_2 = np.where(a == b[:, None])[1]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 191 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0); a = np.random.randint(low=1, high=14, size=9999); b = np.array([7,10,13])' 'ind_3 = np.arange(a.shape[0])[np.in1d(a, b)]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 103 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0); a = np.random.randint(low=1, high=14, size=9999); b = np.array([7,10,13])' 'ind_4 = np.where(np.in1d(a, b))[0]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 63 usec per loo

python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0); a = np.random.randint(low=1, high=14, size=9999); b = np.array([7,10,13])' 'ind_5 = np.where(np.isin(a, b))[0]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 67.1 usec per loop
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be timing the setup commands. Aside from that, nice work.

Comment: Totally agree. I updated the timeit. I'm surprised about the bad performance of ```arange``` against ```where```

Comment: Bad is very relative here.

Comment: I have only tested `ind_1`, and it accomplishes my task! Others will have to try the other methods. Could either @iblasi or @Brenlla clarify the actual operations behind `ind_1`? Correct me if I'm wrong: 
`(summed_rows==common_sums[:,None])` returns True/False array; `any()` method replaces with Boolean 1/0 array; `nonzero()` method returns the indices of all 1's in Boolean array?

Comment: ```(summed_rows==common_sums[:,None])``` makes a ```(3,9999)``` array of bools, where first row tells if if the sample of ```summed_rows``` is a 7, 2nd row if it is a 10 and 3rd if it is a 13. ```any``` is telling in axis=0 (if inside the rows of each column) there is any True value. And ```nonzero``` returns the indices of the elements that are non-zero. So if you want to compare with more ```common_sums```, the array created will be ```(n,9999)``` to be able to check the following operations.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
import numpy as np
summed_rows = np.random.randint(low=1, high=14, size=9999)
common_sums = np.array([7, 10, 13])
new_array = np.where(np.isin(summed_rows, common_sums))
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone loking for this for not equal numbers in the array but nearest equal value, this is a straight forward way to do the same for not exactly equal values. for huge summed_rows, might be memory intensive.

```
    import numpy  
    summed_rows = np.random.randint(low=1, high=14, size=9999) 
    common_sums = np.array([7,10,13])
    
    repeat_array = np.repeat(summed_rows, len(common_sums)).reshape(len(summed_rows), len(common_sums)) 
    search_index = np.argmin(np.abs(repeat_array - common_sums), axis=0)
```