# Add array values to numpy recarray where identifier matches with other array

Tags: python, numpy, recarray

I am trying to assign values from one recarray (`in_arr`) into another (`out_arr`) based on an identifier string in one of the columns. To assign the values correctly, the strings in `id` must match.

Some constraints:

- the number of elements in `in_arr` can be smaller or larger than the number in `out_arr`
- every identifier in `in_arr` is represented in `out_arr`, not necessarily the other way round
- if the number in `in_arr` is larger, entries will repeat and any - single one - of these can be assigned
- every identifier in `out_arr` is unique
- the element order of the result does not matter
- I'd rather not loop throug every element ;-)

Here is some code:

```
my_dtype = [('id', 'S3'), ('val', int)]
in_arr = np.array([('xyz', 1), ('abc', 2), ('abc', 2)], dtype=my_dtype)
out_arr = np.array([('abc', 0), ('asd', 0), ('qwe', 0), ('xyz', 0), ('def', 0)], dtype=my_dtype)

msk_in, msk_out = ... # some magic
out_arr[msk_out]['val'] = in_arr[msk_in]['val']    # <-- other ways to assign also work for me...

out_arr
array([(b'abc', 2), (b'asd', 0), (b'qwe', 0), (b'xyz', 1), (b'def', 0)],
      dtype=[('id', 'S3'), ('val', '<i8')])
```

The closest, I came for replacing my "magic part" is by borrowing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066974/find-indices-of-numpy-array-based-on-values-in-another-numpy-array). But this only gives me the correct indices, not the correct order.

```
np.where(np.isin(out_arr['id'], in_arr['id']))[0]
array([0, 3])
```

Comment: It may be simpler to work with separate arrays rather than `structured` ones like this.  Keeping `id` and `val` together can be handy, but it may complicate your think.  Also be ware of this indexing: `out_arr[msk_out]['val'] = ```.  I would put [`val']` first, since the `msk_out` indexing is boolean and makes a copy.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am reading in both arrays from files, i.e., they are structured from the beginning. But I have no problem splitting them if that makes it easier. Any suggestions on how to proceed from there?

Comment: Actually it should be enough to assign `out_val=out_arr['val']` etc; that should be a `view` that can be referenced and assigned.  But I'm suggesting that just because it might make the code easier to read.  I haven't looked at your logic enough to suggest anything more.

Comment: I tried that, but it also overwrites the `id` values, e.g., `xyz` --> `'1'`, so I kept the second `val` in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by sorting the arrays according to the `id` values.
This requires, to remove duplicates in the `in_arr` first.

```
# remove duplicates
in_arr = in_arr[np.unique(in_arr['id'], return_index=True)[1]]

# sort both arrays to match the first len(in_arr) elements
out_arr = np.array(sorted(out_arr, key=lambda x: (np.isin(x['id'], in_arr['id']), x['id']), reverse=True))
in_arr[::-1].sort(order='id')

# assign values and test
out_arr['val'][:len(in_arr)] = in_arr['val'] 
out_arr
array([(b'xyz', 1), (b'abc', 2), (b'qwe', 0), (b'def', 0), (b'asd', 0)],
      dtype=[('id', 'S3'), ('val', '<i8')])
```